# ExtJS viewport one item accessing another item

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have create a viewport in ExtJS with several layouts (west, center, north). One of these is a grid to which I've added a click handler. This click is supposed to open an HTML or PHP file in one of the layout, but I am not sure how to access the item in the center from the click handler in the west.

```
 Ext.create('Ext.Viewport', {
        layout: {
            type: 'border',
            padding: 5
        },
        defaults: {
            split: true
        },
        items: [{
            region: 'north',
            border:false,
            collapsible: false,
            resizable:false,
            title: 'North',
            split: true,
            height: 30,
            html: 'north'
        },{
            region: 'west',
            collapsible: true,
            title: 'Navigation',
            split: true,
            width: '10%',
            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            itemid:'projectgrid',
            hideHeaders: true,
            columns: [{header: 'NID', dataIndex: 'NavName', flex: 1}],
            store: navStore,
            listeners: {
                itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
                    alert(record.get('NavPage'));
                }
            }

        },{
            region: 'center',
            layout: 'border',
            border: false,
            id: 'renderArea',
            items: [{
                region: 'center',
                html: 'center center',
                title: 'Center',
                items: [cw = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
                    xtype: 'window',
                    closable: false,
                    minimizable: true,
                    title: 'Constrained Window',
                    height: 200,
                    width: 400,
                    constrain: true,
                    html: 'I am in a Container',
                    itemId: 'center-window',
                    minimize: function() {
                        this.floatParent.down('button#toggleCw').toggle();
                    }
                })]
            }]
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the component you want to access an itemId of `foo`, you can do something like this, navigate up to the viewport, then down to find the appropriate viewport child.

`dv.up('viewport').down('#foo')`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. I read somewhere that it was best to avoid this but it does seem like the only option.

Comment: There are a number of ways of doing it, this one is preferred because by using itemId it's local to the container and the query is constrained to the logic of the class.

Comment: The # indicates an itemId/id for the selector.